# How do I connect TF2 to steam client

Tags: team-fortress-2

I was wondering how do I connect TF2 to steam client? When ever I try to go into my backpack, it says I need to connect to steam.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Steam itself. I had to reset my username, so now all my status is gone. Good thing I didn't buy anything until now.